# PyQT: Selecting file and using function on them

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I have the following code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8-*-
import sys, convBB
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.resize(300,300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Convert_BB_test')
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('icon.png'))

        self.buttonSelect = QtGui.QPushButton('Select Files', self)
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonSelect)
        self.buttonSelect.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)

        self.buttonConvert = QtGui.QPushButton('Convert', self)
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonConvert)
        self.buttonConvert.clicked.connect(self.convBB.convert(self.handleButton()))

    def handleButton(self):
        title = self.buttonSelect.text()
        file_list = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self, title)
        for path in file_list:
            print (path)
        #convBB.convert(list)
        return file_list

#if __name__ == '__main__':


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I receive file list from `handleButton` function and want to use function `convBB.convert(list)` (from my `convBB.py`) on this list:

```
self.buttonConvert.clicked.connect(self.convBB.convert(self.handleButton()))
```

and have:

```
AttributeError: 'Window' object has no attribute 'convBB'
```

**How can i select file, with select-button and then convert them with convert-button?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to process the `list` with `buttonCovert` then

1. add the line `self.fileList = []` to in the `__init__` of `Window`
2. add the line `self.fileList = file_list` inside the `handleButton` method right before you return
3. use `self.buttonConvert.clicked.connect(lambda: convBB.convert(self.fileList))` instead of `self.buttonConvert.clicked.connect(self.convBB.convert(self.handleButton()))`

Comment: it works, but it call file dialog again. how can i select file, with select-button and then convert them with convert-button?

Comment: @nuT707 properly add that to the question. So that I shall address it.